# Anaconda installation troubles

Tags: python, windows, installation, anaconda

I am struggling with reinstalling Anaconda. I had Anaconda set up on my system. One day, don't know why, I started to uninstall. But for some reason I cancelled the process before it finished. After that I am trying to install Anaconda, but it's failing. I have searched and deleted all Anaconda and Python folders from my machine. After that I reinstalled Anaconda. After that, when I try to click on Anaconda on start menu, I get the following error.

I am using Windows 10.

[image: Anaconda Navigation Error]

Comment: Did you delete all python versions from your machine?  What about Python 2?  The mac needs python 2 so if you deleted it you will have problems but i don't think you can delete it.

Comment: How did you attempt to uninstall Anaconda?

Comment: @jmh I may have deleted all Python folders. This is windows, not Mac. Not sure if that makes any difference. I uninstalled from Settings -> Apps -> Uninstall

Comment: i'm sorry. i thought i was on a mac site.  Please ignore my comments.

Comment: Please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/.